# Perl $_ variable work mechanism in nested loop

Tags: perl

Here is a part of Perl code with a nested loop, plz ignore undefined variables. I was confused about this `$_` work mechanism in out and in loop.

Hypothesis: @sfiles = A.c B.c C.c

After execution array `@sfiles` will be overridden by inner loop which match `$symbol`.

I am not sure that `$_` is used just like a C pointer to these `@sfile` or open files?

```
foreach (@sfiles) {

  my $fpname = $sdir . '/' . $_;
  open SOURCEFILE, '<', $fpname or die "Failed to open file [$fpname].  $!";

  while (<SOURCEFILE>) {
    chomp;
    next if /\/\//;

    if (/\/\*/) {
      while (<SOURCEFILE>) {
        chomp;
        last if /\*\//;
      }
    }
    if (/$symbol/) {
      $reference = 'refered';
      last;
    }
  }

  close(SOURCEFILE);

  last if $reference;
}
```

Comment: `$_ *=2 for my @r =1..5; print "@r"` so foreach variable(`$_`) is here aliased to `@r` array elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend avoiding `$_` for almost all situations. It was suppose to make your code *more English like*, but it really doesn't improve readability:

```
for ( @array ) {
    next unless /^foo/;
    print;
}
```

Is that really more readable than this?

```
for my $item ( @array ) {
    next unless $item =~ /^foo/;
    print "$item\n";
}
```

Nor, does it have any sort of magic properties (as [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23019039/368630) hinted in his answer) that another variables would not have. Any variable, and not just `$_` would be aliased to the element in a `for` loop. In this program, I change `three` to `buzz` in my array by simply changing the value of the variable `$item`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw(one two three four five);

for my $item ( @array ) {
    if ( $item eq "three" ) {
        $item = "buzz";   # Will actually change $array[2]
    }
}

#
# Let's print out my array and see if $array[2] got changed.
#
for my $item ( @array ) {
    print "$item\n";
}
```

This prints out:

```
one
two
buzz
four
five
```

Even worse, `$_` raises it's ugly head anyway in any loop longer than a few lines. In your example, you have:

```
my $fpname = $sdir . '/' . $_;
```

So much for being invisible.

In your example, you noticed that the value of `$_` seems to keep working in both the inner and outer loop. That is, even though I'm using the same variable, somehow the two loops don't interfere with each other.

That's because `$_` is *localized* for each loop.  It's one of those Perl mishmash concepts that non-Perl developers rant and rave about.

`$_` is the same variable in both loops. `$_` is global in scope. However, in each loop, the value that this global variable contains is *localized* to the scope of the loop. Huh? See [local](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) and get ready to have your mind blown. It usually takes a few years for someone to learn the difference between a *package (aka globally) scoped variable*, a *lexically (aka locally) scoped variable*, and a *package scoped (aka global) variable that's localized*. No wonder why all the Python programmers make fun of me.

As [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23018207/368630) stated, although using `$_` happens to work, your program is would be easier to understand if you used an actual variable in each loop.  Besides, imagine what would happen if you had need the name of the file that the line came from in your `while` loop. (`warn`The line $_ in file $_ is not in the right format";`).

You may want to use *labels* when you have loops within loops. A label can be used to tell which loop a `next` or `last` should be going to:

```
FILE:
for my $source_file ( @files ) {
   open my $source_fh, "<", $source_file;   # Use autodie...
   LINE:
   while ( my $line = <$file> ) {
      ...
      ...
      next LINE if ...   # Don't need this line
      ...
      ...
      next FILE if ...  # I'm done with this file
      ...
   }
}
```

Even if you don't use `next FILE` like I did, a label simply makes your program a bit cleaner. You're not merely going to the next iteration of the loop, you're going to the next **LINE** of the file.

Comment: Thanks, I did not have a deep understanding of localized in perl, because my routine work always be C. Thanks again for your clearly and correct description. I would like to learn about this.

Comment: The information is a bit scattered. Take a look at the Perldoc on [Perl Subroutines](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) and read the parts of the _Temporary Variables via "my"_ and _Temporary Variables via "local"_. Also look at the Perldoc on [Perl Modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) for a discussion on namespace and the _symbol table_. In Perl before 5.x, all variables are _symbol table_ variables and if you needed to localize the value, you used `local`. Perl 5 introduced _my variables_ and `use strict;`

Comment: Finaly after 5 hours i found the bug.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, foreach aliases the loop variable to the elements being looped over.  For this reason, you are often better off not using the default variable but instead doing:

```
foreach my $file (@sfiles) {
    ...
    while ( my $line = <SOURCEFILE> ) {
       ...
```

Comment: And have the positive side effect that the code becomes readable, and you can follow the logic.